# Javascript: How to transform for loop to use promises?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise

I want to create a nested object, and save each lowest level before the upper level (so that my nested object is properly created)..

Currently here is my non working code. I heard that to make it work, I had to use Promises. I am stuck as I don't know how I should start a promise in my for loops

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {
    var Test0 = Parse.Object.extend("Test0");
    var test0 = new Test0();
    var array0 = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
        var Test1 = Parse.Object.extend("Test1");
        var test1 = new Test1();
        var array1 = new Array();
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
            var Test2 = Parse.Object.extend("Test2");
            var test2 = new Test2();
            test2.set("foo","bar");
            array1.push(test2);
            test2.save()
        }
        test1.set("foo","bar");
        test1.set("array1",array1);
        array0.push(test1);
        test1.save();
    }
    test0.set("foo","bar");
    test0.set("array0", array0);
    test0.save(null, {
success: function(result) {
            response.success("success");
        },
error: function(result, error) {
            alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
            response.error("error");
        }
    });
});
```

How should I modify this code so that my save for test1 only happens when all of its test2 childs have properly terminated their own save? I will apply the same logic for test0

Comment: Let me know if the technique there is not clear enough and I'll write a new answer - it's a very similar question, you chain a for loop by creating an empty promise `p` and then doing `p = p.then(...` in a loop.

Comment: I get the idea, but would love to see some code here in this topic... Thanks!

Comment: Well, now I'm confused, are you stuck on the same issue (transforming a loop to use promises) or something else?

Comment: Still stuck with transforming the loop in promises. It's because they are nested so I don't know where to start....

Comment: Would an answer here that explains how to generally convert nested loops to promises be helpful?

Comment: Yes, or just a working modification of the code I posted. Thanks!!

Comment: A working modification of the code you posted isn't going to happen, sorry. What you need is something along the lines of `var p = Parse.Promise.as("");` for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) for(var j = 0;j < 10; j++) p = p.then(function(){ return asyncOp(); })` - this will chain a 100 actions, 10 for each i on each `j`. In your case - the async action is the `.save` and since you have two loops you might have to nest the `.then`s

Comment: Fair enough! I will try things out and let you know. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Benjamin, I got it working! I now need to optimize my calls... but I fully understand it. You're my god